# Regex: find "m:ss, mm:ss or hh:mm:ss", no 'lookbehind' and reject substring and invalid values

Tags: javascript, regex

Requirements:

- No 'lookbehind' in the regex (Safari not supporting it)
- prioritize `MM:SS` (59:59) over `HH:MM` (23:59) for the 5-character case
- Allow `M:SS`
- Must reject invalid items as a whole (no substrings)

I'm having a hard time trying to reject invalid values for a timestamp. Here's a sample expected output:

```
    01:02 and 01:23       // Match: "01:02", "01:23"
    03:23:11 blah         // Match: "03:23:11"
    100:100:232           // Match: None (don't match the substring!)
    100:123:232           // Match: None (don't match the substring!)
    4444:123:23           // Match: None (don't match the substring!)
    Hello 23:00:01        // Match "23:00:01"
    Hello 23:00:01999     // Match: None (can accept partially highlighting "23:00:01",
                          //        but best if can reject the entire item.
    11:22::33             // Match: "11:22" (double-colon or trailing will be ignored)
    9:00:23               // Match: "9:00:23"
    0:10                  // Match: "0:10"
    blah 0:10             // Match: "0:10"
    nospaces23:44nospaces // Match: "23:44"
    Blah 2:56 - 00:45:00  // Match: "2:56", "00:45:00"
    Blah 2:56 - 45:00     // Match: "2:56", "45:00"
    2:398                 // Match: None
    2:39                  // Match: 2:39
    00:12 - 02:34:        // Match: "00:12", "02:34" (trailing colon can be ignored)
    59:01                 // Match: "59:01"
    62:02                 // Match: None (don't accept "2:02"!)
```

The closest I got is this:

```
/((2[0-3]|[01][0-9]|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])|([0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])|([0-9]:[0-5][0-9])/g
```

Comment: *"prioritize MM:SS over HH:SS"* Your title doesn't allow for HH:SS (or hh:ss), just hh:mm:ss.

Comment: typo corrected.

Comment: I'd actually read right past the typo. :-) My point was that your title says it should handle `m:ss` or `mm:ss` or `hh:mm:ss`, not `hh:mm`.

Comment: @secan, no, yours has similar results to mine. Instead of rejecting "62:02" entirely, it matched "2:02" instead.  Same goes for the "100:100:232" case.

Comment: Sorry, I noticed it later; _this_ should do the trick: `/(?<=(^| ))([0-2]?[0-6]:)?([0-5]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])(?=($| ))/g`

Comment: @Thefourthbird typo in the results part.  I think "11:22" should be the match, but rejecting entirely is fine too.

Comment: @Ryuu Like this? `(?:^|\D)([0-5]?\d:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?)(?!:?\d)` https://regex101.com/r/OJcgtV/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird it eats up the previous character (usually a space). For the case of "nospaces23:44nospaces", "s23:44" was matched.  It's pretty close (trying to play around with it), but this case is needed for those Asian non-spaced languages.

Comment: @Ryuu But the value that you want to match `23:44` is in the capturing group, is that not desired?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed with negative lookbehind and negative lookahead

```
/(?<!\d)[0-5]?\d:\d{2}(?::*\d{2})?(?!:?\d)/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/Nz7Duh/2/

Comment: Ah, I missed out this important part.  No lookbehind as Safari doesn't support it.

Comment: Lookbehinds might be not necessary with this workaround http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You might use a capturing group with a negative lookahead:

```
(?:^|\D)([0-5]?\d:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?)(?!:?\d)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:^|\D)` Assert the start of the string or match any char except a digit
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[0-5]?\d:\d{2}` Optionally match a digit 0-5, match a digit 0-9 `:`` and 2 digits
- `(?::\d{2})?` Optionally match `:` and 2 digits
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?!:?\d)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not an optional `:` followed by a digit

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MdMLQz/1)

```js
const regex = /(?:^|\D)([0-5]?\d:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?)(?!:?\d)/g;
[
  "01:02 and 01:23",
  "03:23:11 blah",
  "100:100:232",
  "100:123:232",
  "4444:123:23",
  "Hello 23:00:01",
  "Hello 23:00:01999",
  "11:22::33",
  "9:00:23",
  "0:10",
  "blah 0:10",
  "nospaces23:44nospaces",
  "Blah 2:56 - 00:45:00",
  "Blah 2:56 - 45:00",
  "2:398",
  "2:39",
  "00:12 - 02:34:",
  "59:01",
  "62:02",
].forEach(s => console.log(Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[1])));
```